# ListView is not reload with StatefulWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making one demo for learning purpose. In that demo I have just added `ListView` and when I tap on the `ListTile` there is `Icons.favorite` I just want to do Active and Deactive.

Below are my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new RandomWordApp());

class RandomWordApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Random App",
      home: new RandomWordHome(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWordHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new RandomState();
}

class RandomState extends State<RandomWordHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Random Word"),
      ),
      body: setupListView(),
    );
  }

  Widget setupListView() {
    final _arrayOfData = [
      {
        "name": "Amit Patel",
        "address": "Junagadh"
      },
      {"name": "Arjun Jain", "address": "Madhya Pradesh"},
      {"name": "Ajay Shah", "address": "Limbadi"},
      {"name": "Ankur Patel", "address": "Visanagar"},
      {"name": "Soheb Ansari", "address": "Ahmedabad"}
    ];    
    final _arraySelectedRowStatus = List.filled(5, 0);

    return new ListView.builder(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: _arrayOfData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["name"]),
            subtitle: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["address"]),
            leading: new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                child: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["name"][0])),
            trailing: new Icon(
              (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0
                  ? Icons.favorite_border
                  : Icons.favorite),
              color: (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0 ? null : Colors.red),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  _arraySelectedRowStatus[i] =
                      (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0 ? 1 : 0);         
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                      content:
                          new Text("You are selecting at " + i.toString())));
                },
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

All are working well, even I got expected output from below line

```
print(_arrayOfData[i]["name"] + " - " + _arraySelectedRowStatus[i].toString());
```

But `Icon` is not change might be because ListView is not reloading. Where I'm going wrong? Guide me on right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your approach

1. In order to update your UI, you have to use setState() method. Changing the variable is not enough.
2. You always create a final List inside ListView.builder block: ***final _arraySelectedRowStatus = List.filled(5, 0);*** and then use this list to render your UI. So the _arraySelectedRowStatus will always contain **0**.

Below is updated code which will work

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new RandomWordApp());

class RandomWordApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Random App",
      home: new RandomWordHome(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWordHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new RandomState();
}

class RandomState extends State<RandomWordHome> {
  List _arraySelectedRowStatus = List.filled(5, 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Random Word"),
      ),
      body: setupListView(),
    );
  }

  Widget setupListView() {
    final _arrayOfData = [
      {"name": "Amit Patel", "address": "Junagadh"},
      {"name": "Arjun Jain", "address": "Madhya Pradesh"},
      {"name": "Ajay Shah", "address": "Limbadi"},
      {"name": "Ankur Patel", "address": "Visanagar"},
      {"name": "Soheb Ansari", "address": "Ahmedabad"}
    ];

    return new ListView.builder(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: _arrayOfData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["name"]),
            subtitle: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["address"]),
            leading: new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                child: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["name"][0])),
            trailing: new Icon(
              (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0
                  ? Icons.favorite_border
                  : Icons.favorite),
              color: (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0 ? null : Colors.red),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              _arraySelectedRowStatus[i] =
                  (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0 ? 1 : 0);
              print(_arrayOfData[i]["name"] +
                  " - " +
                  _arraySelectedRowStatus[i].toString());

              setState(() {
                _arraySelectedRowStatus = _arraySelectedRowStatus;
              });

              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                  content: new Text("You are selecting at " + i.toString())));
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Update]

Here is the complete working code.

```
class DemoHelp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Random App",
      home: RandomWorldHome(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWorldHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomWorldHomeState createState() => new _RandomWorldHomeState();
}

class _RandomWorldHomeState extends State<RandomWorldHome> {

  List<int> _arraySelectedRowStatus = List.filled(5, 1);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Random Word"),
      ),
      body: setupListView(),
    );
  }

  Widget setupListView() {
    final _arrayOfData = [
      {"name": "Amit Patel", "address": "Junagadh"},
      {"name": "Arjun Jain", "address": "Madhya Pradesh"},
      {"name": "Ajay Shah", "address": "Limbadi"},
      {"name": "Ankur Patel", "address": "Visanagar"},
      {"name": "Soheb Ansari", "address": "Ahmedabad"}
    ];


    return ListView.builder(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: _arrayOfData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(_arrayOfData[i]["name"]),
          subtitle: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["address"]),
          leading: new CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: new Text(_arrayOfData[i]["name"][0])),
          trailing: new Icon(
            (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0
                ? Icons.favorite_border
                : Icons.favorite),
            color: (_arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0 ? null : Colors.red),
          ),
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              _arraySelectedRowStatus[i] = _arraySelectedRowStatus[i] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            });
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                content:
                new Text("You are selecting at ${_arraySelectedRowStatus[i]}")));
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Couple of problems in your code.

1. variable _arraySelectedRowStatus is wrongly defined as final
2. state variable should be declared in the state class rather than in method.
3. setState((){}) is used like this.

Comment: Removed it but didn't reflect to output

Comment: @Govaadiyo Please check the updated answer with working code and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for answer It improved my knowledge.